# Scala's Stream and StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, stream, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation

Consider this code (taken from "[Functional programming principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun)" course by Martin Odersky):

```
def sieve(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  s.head #:: sieve(s.tail.filter(_ % s.head != 0))
}

val primes = sieve(Stream.from(2))
primes.take(1000).toList
```

It works just fine. Notice that `sieve` is in fact NOT tail recursive (or is it?), even though `Stream`'s tail is lazy.

But this code:

```
def sieve(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  n #:: sieve(n + 1).filter(_ % n != 0)
}

val primes = sieve(2)
primes.take(1000).toList
```

throws `StackOverflowError`.

What is the problem with the second example? I guess `filter` messes things up, but I can't understand why. It returns a `Stream`, so it souldn't make evaluation eager (am I right?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can highlight the problem with a bit of tracking code:

```
var counter1, counter2 = 0

def sieve1(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  counter1 += 1
  s.head #:: sieve1(s.tail.filter(_ % s.head != 0))
}

def sieve2(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  counter2 += 1
  n #:: sieve2(n + 1).filter(_ % n != 0)
}

sieve1(Stream.from(2)).take(100).toList
sieve2(2).take(100).toList
```

We can run this and check the counters:

```
scala> counter1
res2: Int = 100

scala> counter2
res3: Int = 540
```

So in the first case the depth of the call stack is the number of primes, and in the second it's the largest prime itself (well, minus one).

Comment: Thank you! So, both examples would overflow the stack, but second just makes it faster. The thing that got me confused was why the 1st example doesn't do that, when it is not tail recursive. Now I see.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. The first one _will not_ blow up the stack. The #:: is intentionally lazy.

Comment: The issue was almost certainly the position of the filter outside the tail call, which possibly built up a large depth of streams to pull from. (The counting was just counting invocations, _not_ stack depth). Also, I can't either form this to overflow with scala 2.10, so perhaps the filter method on Stream has been improved since then.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one of these are tail recursive.

Using the [tailrec](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/package.html) annotation will tell you whether or not a function is tail recursive.

Adding  @tailrec to the two functions above gives:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def sieve(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  s.head #:: sieve(s.tail.filter(_ % s.head != 0))
}

@tailrec
def sieve(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  n #:: sieve(n + 1).filter(_ % n != 0)
}
```

Loading this shows that both definitions are not tail recursive:

```
<console>:10: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method sieve: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
         s.head #:: sieve(s.tail.filter(_ % s.head != 0))
                ^
<console>:10: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method sieve: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
         n #:: sieve(n + 1).filter(_ % n != 0)
```

Comment: Yes, I know both examples are not tail recursive, I just wondered why the 1st one works fine when 2nd fails. Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is that they will both blow up the stack. The second one just does it sooner than the first one. Try `sieve1` with progressively larger numbers.

Comment: That's not true. The #:: method is lazy, so the evaluation of the recursive call is deferred.

Comment: @ChrisLeishman I thought so, too. However, tailrec does complain and using take(10000) instead of take(100) causes a OutOfMemoryError for me.

Comment: It's not tailrec, so the tailrec annotation should complain. Indeed, it's technically not recursive at all, because the recursive part is deferred.